# Ruby rails error: Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":

The error is below

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    bundler (~> 2.2)

    rails (= 6.1.4.6) was resolved to 6.1.4.6, which depends on
      bundler (>= 2.2.0)

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (2.1.4)
This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?

Could not find gem 'bundler (~> 2.2)', which is required by gem 'rails (= 6.1.4.6)', in any of the relevant sources:
  the local ruby installation
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is actually in the error message that you are getting. Run

```
gem install bundler
```

to install the latest version of bundler (that should satisfy the constraints

You can also specify a particular version of any gem by specifying the version flag. For example.

```
gem install bundler -v 2.2.0
```

Comment: I've already done that but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

`gem install bundler --version 2.2.19 --default`